# Convolutional Neural Network for heat map kind of images

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

Can I use CNN architecture for binary classification on these types of images (posted below)?

Currently, I am it having 3-Conv + 2-FC layers but not getting good results. I have a sufficient amount of data as well. I tried transfer learning with Inception V3 but it is overfitting in all cases of layer locking.

1. Is there any separate way of classifying such images because the features to be extracted are limited here.
2. Semantic Segmentation converts images into a kind of pixel-wise color maps but it is total different paradigm.

[image: Class-1]
[image: Class-2]

Comment: How did you solved it?